# Jump Year value in jQuery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to jump my date picker calendar value from 2050 to 9999.
After 31/12/2050, the date picker's calendar dropdown should display directly and only year 9999.

Is this feasible in jQuery?

Awaiting the valuable responses.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selector").datepicker({
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, i) {
    if (year > 2050) {
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(9999, 01, 01));
    }
  }
});
```